# how to read postfix mail from command line

Tags: mail-command

I have setup *postfix* server and set `home_mailbox = Mail/`. How to make `mail` read mail from `~/Mail/`. I tried `ln -s ~/Mail /var/mail/$USER` but `mail` complains `Cannot open mailbox /var/mail/$USER: Is a directory`

Comment: Apparently `mail` expects mbox, but you're giving it maildir. For that you need something that can read maildir, like `mutt`.

Comment: can't postfix be configured to deliver in mbox?

Comment: Sure. It uses maildir when it sees trailing slash in `home_mailbox`, and mailbox when there's none. So just drop the slash: `home_mailbox = mbox`

Comment: thanks! I just configured dovecot's mail.conf to read mail from /var/mail/%u